# How to uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 which is in dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 20.04

I have got a dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 with Ubuntu 20.04.
How do I uninstall Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

I have a dual boot of ubuntu with windows, what I do to eliminate the operating system is to eliminate the partition where I have it mounted. you could try to delete the partition of the disk where ubuntu 16.04 is, here comes information on how to do it,but be very careful not to uninstall 20.04
[delete the partition of the disk where ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/#:~:text=Use%20the%20d%20command%20to,view%20the%20current%20partition%20table.)

Comment: You are forgetting the grub / bootloader settings.

Comment: I have been deleting the partition where the 16.04 on was, succesfully. It was on another drive than I thought it was. So the command `sudo fdisk -l` to list the partitions was helpfull.